# Shifting and Masking Binary Bits

Tags: bit, masking

I've came across this snippet of code on a book:

```
    public static short countBits(int x) {
        short numBit =  0;
        while(x != 0) {
            numBit +=  (x&1);
            x >>>= 1;
        }
        return numBit;
    }
```

However, I'm not really sure how `numBit +=  (x&1);` and `x >>>= 1`  works.
I think that `numBit +=  (x&1)` is comparing AND for a single digit and 1. Does it mean that if my binary number is 10001, the function is ANDing the 1000"1" bit with 1 on the first iteration of the while loop?
Also, what's the point of >>>= 1 ? I think that ">>>" is shifting the bits to the right by three but I can't figure out the purpose of doing so in this function.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function counts the number of bits that are set to "1". `x & 1` is a bitwise-AND with the least significant bit of `x`'s current value (either 1 if `x` is odd, or 0 if it's even). As such it makes perfect sense to add it to result. `x >>>= 1` is equivalent to `x = x >> 1` and this means "shift bits in `x` by 1 position to the right" (or, for unsigned integers, divide `x` by 2).